# Wrong color on Unity Shader Graph

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, shader-graph

I have car mesh for my game. I need change base car color without wheel and headlights color. For this I create texture with white and black places where need changes and color mask for it. Then I created shader with Shader Graph[image]

But the color I got is wrong. It's brighter.
The Color what I want and what I have:
[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're using negative inputs, Add won't reduce the amount of blue, red, or green. Since you're adding red light into grey, you'll get pink as a result. Instead, you should use Multiply.

Multiply the base texture with a white-based color map, where the color map is white where it shouldn't affect the base texture. To make the white-based color map, you can invert the result of the color mask and add it to the result of the multiply you already have.

[image: example graph]